# Is there a way to integrate dynamic content on the sidebar of the related post on WordPress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Is there a way to integrate dynamic content on the sidebar of the post on WordPress? I want to load a video on click as a pop up or it pop ups on top of the actual writing content... when clicked on the sidebar. I attached 2 images for examples...

**1. This is the original screenshot of what a post looks like.**

[image]

**2. I want to integrate the video here on the sidebar on top of the translate widget. (Im not a photo editing person)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need create new widget. It's class who extend WP_Widget and register him `register_widget( $widget_class )`. More here https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/widgets/

Comment: So create a new widget but how would I go about attaching the videos to its related post?

Comment: You can create text field and add url or create media field and add video from library

Answer (score 0):

You can use acf plugin to create a field to each post ( [or you can create a wordpress metabox and save as post meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/custom-meta-boxes/)), so in your widget, the video url will be the acf field value or the meta information that you will collect on metabox.